# Trouble getting the trade-price using "Requests-HTML" library

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I've written a script in python to get the price of last trade from a javascript rendered webpage. I can get the content If I choose to go with `selenium`. My goal here is not to use any browser simulator like `selenium` or something because the latest release of [Requests-HTML](http://html.python-requests.org/en/latest/) is supposed to have the ability to parse javascript encrypted content. However, I am not being able to make a go successfully. When I run the script, I get the following error. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Site address : [webpage_link](https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR)

The script I've tried with:

```
import requests_html

with requests_html.HTMLSession() as session:
    r = session.get('https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR')
    js = r.html.render()
    item = js.find('.MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs',first=True).text
    print(item)
```

This is the complete traceback:

```
Exception in callback NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py:49
handle: <Handle NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py:49>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py", line 52, in watchdog_cb
    self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py", line 40, in _raise_error
    raise error
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 3000 ms exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\experiment.py", line 6, in <module>
    item = js.find('.MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs',first=True).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\shutil.py", line 387, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\ar\\.pyppeteer\\.dev_profile\\tmp1gng46sw\\CrashpadMetrics-active.pma'
```

The price I'm after is available on the top of the page which can be visible like this `177.59 EUR Last trade price`. I wish to get `177.59` or whatever the current price is.

Comment: Could it be due to the `render` function not returning the result object, but the result object still being `r`? What happens if you do `r.html.search(...)`?

Comment: No improvement is there. I tried with `.search()` and got this error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have several errors. The first is a 'navigation' timeout, showing that the page didn’t complete rendering:

```
Exception in callback NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py:49
handle: <Handle NavigatorWatcher.waitForNavigation.<locals>.watchdog_cb(<Task finishe...> result=None>) at C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py:49>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 145, in _run
    self._callback(*self._args)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py", line 52, in watchdog_cb
    self._timeout)
  File "C:\Users\ar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\pyppeteer\navigator_watcher.py", line 40, in _raise_error
    raise error
concurrent.futures._base.TimeoutError: Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 3000 ms exceeded
```

This traceback is not raised in the main thread, your code was not aborted because of this. Your page may or may not be complete; you may want to set a longer timeout or introduce a sleep cycle for the browser to have time to process AJAX responses.

Next, the `response.html.render()` element **returns `None`**. It loads the HTML into a headless Chromium browser, leaves JavaScript rendering to that browser, then copies back the page HTML into the `response.html` datasctructure *in place*, and nothing needs to be returned. So `js` is set to `None`, not a new `HTML` instance, causing your next traceback.

Use the *existing* `response.html` object to search, after rendering:

```
r.html.render()
item = r.html.find('.MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs', first=True)
```

There is *most likely* no such CSS class, because the last 5 characters are *generated* on each page render, after JSON data is loaded over AJAX. This makes it hard to use CSS to find the element in question.

Moreover, I found that without a sleep cycle, the browser has no time to fetch AJAX resources and render the information you wanted to load. Give it, say, 10 seconds of `sleep` to do some work before copying back the HTML. Set a longer timeout (the default is 8 seconds) if you see network timeouts:

```
r.html.render(timeout=10, sleep=10)
```

You could set the `timeout` to `0` too, to remove the timeout and just wait indefinitely until the page has loaded.

Hopefully [a future API update](https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/89) also provides features to [wait for network activity to cease](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/reference.html#pyppeteer.page.Page.waitForNavigation).

You can use the [included `parse` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) to find the matching CSS classes:

```
# search for CSS suffixes
suffixes = [r[0] for r in r.html.search_all('MarketInfo_market-num_{:w}')]
for suffix in suffixes:
    # for each suffix, find all matching elements with that class
    items = r.html.find('.MarketInfo_market-num_{}'.format(suffix))
    for item in items:
        print(item.text)
```

Now we get output produced:

```
169.81 EUR
+
1.01 %
18,420 LTC
169.81 EUR
+
1.01 %
18,420 LTC
169.81 EUR
+
1.01 %
18,420 LTC
169.81 EUR
+
1.01 %
18,420 LTC
```

Your last traceback shows that the Chromium user data path could not be cleaned up. The underlying [Pyppeteer library](https://miyakogi.github.io/pyppeteer/) configures the headless Chromium browser with a temporary user data path, and in your case the directory contains some still-locked resource. You can ignore the error, although you may want to try and remove any remaining files in the `.pyppeteer` folder at a later time.

Comment: You are very right about putting some delay and fixing css selector. The selector used in the above script is faulty because it is generated dynamically. I tried with `[class^='MarketInfo_market-num_']` and `r.html.render(sleep=10)`. I'm getting result now. The errors are still there along with desired result. Is there any way I can get rid of errors?

Comment: @SIM: if you see `TimeoutError`s, set a larger `timeout=` value when rendering. Or set it to 0 to remove the timeout altogether.

Comment: r.html.render(timeout=10, sleep=10) in my case it starts a new session and again parses login page, any idea why ?

Comment: @Pritish: nope, sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need it to go through Requests-HTML? On the day you posted, the repo was 4 days old and in the 3 days that have passed there have been 50 commits. It's not going to be completely stable for some time.

See here:
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests-html/graphs/commit-activity

OTOH, there is an API for gdax.

https://docs.gdax.com/#market-data

Now if you're dead set on using Py3, there is a python client listed on the GDAX website. Upfront I'll mention that it's the unofficial client; however, if you use this you'd be able to quickly and easily get responses from the official GDAX api.

https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python

Comment: @shayan: then pick a site that doesn't cause issues right now. By the looks of it, the page just failed to load extra resources.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to use another way by running Selenium web scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


chrome_path = r"C:\Users\Mike\Desktop\chromedriver.exe"    

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.get("https://www.gdax.com/trade/LTC-EUR")

item = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//span[@class='MarketInfo_market-num_1lAXs']''') 
item = item.text
print item
driver.close()
```

result:177.60 EUR